# How to run a action 1 time ONLY in while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to run 1 time ONLY in while loop.

```
while True:
    print("Hello World")#this word always print
    print("HI")#this word print 1 time only
```

Comment: use `break` to get out of the loop?

Comment: don't use `while` why use a loop if you only want it to run once

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep printing `Hello World` but the second line should only print once?

Comment: Could you maybe further elaborate ? what you're doing with `white True` is essentialy making an infinite loop.

Comment: @crimson589 yes i mean keep printing Hello World but the second line should only print one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a validation logic to it

```py
x = False
while True:
    print("Hello World")
    if x == False:
        print("HI")
        x = True
```

Comment: ok. It actually work but change true = True, false = False

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what your use case is... but just add a "break" to end the loop.

```
while True:
    print("Hello World")
    print("This words should show 1 time")
    break
```

Edit based on your comment...

```
ran = False
while True:
    print("Hello World")
    If not ran
        print("This words should show 1 time")
        ran = True
```

Comment: I mean do some actions in while loop 1 time and the other action will run forerver

Comment: @Newbie why do you want to put the "first action" in a loop if you want to run it once ? Just put the "second action" in a loop and leave the first one out of it

Comment: @Newbie I updated my answer for what you want to do.